# How to fix remove() javascript on my script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all i need help with add and remove form element on the fly using jquery.
Add button is already work, but i have no idea with remove button. Currently my script remove all added form not one by one.

script at http://jsfiddle.net/p7m7b15x/1/

```
  var currentItem = 1;
  $('#addnew').click(function(){
   currentItem++;
   $('#items').val(currentItem);
var strToAdd = '<tr class="data"><td>'+currentItem+'</td><td><select name="pnbp_umum'+currentItem+'" id="pnbp_umum'+currentItem+'" ><option selected>Pilih Jenis PNBP</option><option value="423100" disabled>423100 : Pendapatan dari Pengelolaan BMN (Pemanfaatan dan Pendapatan dari Penjualan)</option><option value="423110" disabled>423110 : Pendapatan Penjualan Hasil Produksi/Sitaan</option><option value="423114">423114 : Pendapatan Penjualan Hasil Sitaan/Rampasan dan Harta Peninggalan</option><option value="423115">423115 : Pendapatan Penjualan Obat-obatan dan Hasil Farmasi Lainnya</option><option value="423116">423116 : Pendapatan Penjualan Informasi, Penerbitan, Film, Survey, Pemetaan dan Hasil Cetakan Lainnya</option><option value="423117">423117 : Pendapatan Penjualan Dokumen-dokumen Pelelangan</option><option value="423118">423118 : Pendapatan Penjualan Cadangan Beras Pemerintah Dalam Rangka Operasi Pasar Murni</option><option value="423119">423119 : Pendapatan Penjualan Lainnya</option><option value="423120" disabled>423120 : Pendapatan dari Pemindahtanganan BMN</option><option value="423121">423121 : Pendapatan dari Penjualan Tanah, Gedung, dan Bangunan</option><option value="423122">423122 : Pendapatan dari Penjualan Peralatan dan Mesin</option><option value="423123">423123 : Pendapatan Penjualan Sewa Beli</option><option value="423124">423124 : Pendapatan Penjualan Aset Bekas Milik Asing/Cina</option><option value="423125">423125 : Pendapatan dari Tukar Menukar Tanah, Gedung dan Bangunan</option><option value="423126">423126 : Pendapatan dari Tukar Menukar Peralatan dan Mesin</option><option value="423127">423127 : Pendapatan dari Tukar Menukar Jalan, Irigasi dan Jaringan</option><option value="423129">423129 : Pendapatan dari Pemindahtanganan BMN Lainnya</option><option value="423140" disabled>423140 : Pendapatan dari Pemanfaatan BMN</option><option value="423141">423141 : Pendapatan Sewa Tanah, Gedung, dan Bangunan</option><option value="423142">423142 : Pendapatan Sewa Peralatan dan Mesin</option><option value="423143">423143 : Pendapatan Sewa Jalan, Irigasi dan Jaringan</option><option value="423144">423144 : Pendapatan dari KSP Tanah, Gedung, dan Bangunan</option><option value="423145">423145 : Pendapatan dari KSP Peralatan dan Mesin</option><option value="423146">423146 : Pendapatan dari KSP Jalan, Irigasi dan Jaringan</option><option value="423147">423147 : Pendapatan dari Bangun, Guna, Serah (BGS)</option><option value="423148">423148 : Pendapatan dari Bangun, Serah, Guna (BSG)</option><option value="423149">423149 : Pendapatan dari Pemanfaatan BMN Lainnya</option><option value="423200" disabled>423200 : Pendapatan Jasa</option><option value="423210" disabled>423210 : Pendapatan Jasa I</option><option value="423211">423211 : Pendapatan Rumah Sakit dan Instansi Kesehatan Lainnya</option><option value="423213">423213 : Pendapatan Surat Keterangan, Visa, Paspor</option><option value="423214">423214 : Pendapatan Hak dan Perijinan</option><option value="423215">423215 : Pendapatan Sensor/Karantina, Pengawasan/Pemeriksaan</option><option value="423216">423216 : Pendapatan Jasa Tenaga, Pekerjaan, Informasi, Pelatihan Dan Teknologi</option><option value="423220" disabled>423220 : Pendapatan Jasa II</option><option value="423221">423221 : Pendapatan Jasa Lembaga Keuangan (Jasa Giro)</option><option value="423222">423222 : Pendapatan Jasa Penyelenggaraan Telekomunikasi</option><option value="423227">423227 : Pendapatan Bea Lelang</option><option value="423228">423228 : Pendapatan Biaya Pengurusan Piutang dan Lelang Negara</option><option value="423700" disabled>423700 : Pendapatan Iuran dan Denda</option><option value="423750" disabled>423750 : Pendapatan Denda</option><option value="423752">423752 : Pendapatan Denda Keterlambatan Penyelesaian Pekerjaan Pemerintah</option><option value="423900" disabled>423900 : Pendapatan Lain-lain</option><option value="423910" disabled>423910 : Pendapatan dari Penerimaan Kembali Tahun Anggaran Yang Lalu</option><option value="423911">423911 : Penerimaan Kembali Belanja Pegawai Pusat TAYL</option><option value="423912">423912 : Penerimaan Kembali Belanja Pensiun TAYL</option><option value="423913">423913 : Penerimaan Kembali Belanja Lainnya TAYL</option><option value="423920" disabled>423920 : Pendapatan Pelunasan Piutang</option><option value="423921">423921 : Pendapatan Pelunasan Piutang Non Bendahara</option><option value="423922">423922 : Pendapatan Pelunasan TP/TGR</option><option value="423930" disabled>423930 : Pendapatan dari Penutupan Rekening</option><option value="423931">423931 : Pendapatan dari Penutupan Rekening</option><option value="423990" disabled>423990 : Pendapatan Lain-lain</option><option value="423991">423991 : Penerimaan Kembali Persekot/Uang Muka Gaji</option><option value="423996">423996 : Pendapatan Jasa Perbendaharaan</option><option value="423997">423997 : Pendapatan Kelebihan Pelimpahan Pajak/PNBP dari Bank/Pos Persepsi</option><option value="423999">423999 : Pendapatan Anggaran Lain-lain</option></select></td><td><input name="jumlah'+currentItem+'" id="jumlah'+currentItem+'" type="text" /></td><td></td></tr>';
   $('#data').append(strToAdd);

  });
  $("#remove").click(function () {
    if(currentItem==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

    currentItem--;

        $(".data").remove();

     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) jQuery selector:

```
$("#remove").click(function () {
    $(".data:last-child").remove();
});
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dethariel/p7m7b15x/2/).

Comment: @PNBP I'm glad we helped you. If so, please mark one of answers that fixed your problem as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to remove *only* the last element:

```
$("#remove").click(function () {
     $(".data").last().remove();
});
```

You won't have to keep track of the amount of items in `#data` like this, either.